# How do I download vlc media player? E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center, downloads, software-sources

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend. It is held by process 3476 (aptd)
N: Be aware that removing the lock file is not a solution and may break your system.
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?

Comment: `sudo kill -15 3476`   Or wait untill aptd is ready.

Comment: Simply restart your computer and try it again.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahithis is Ubuntu / Linux .. not Windows. Restart is almost never a correct or lasting solution on a problem.

Comment: @SorenA I know (by experience) that restarting is the simplest solution to this particular problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` is used by the automatic updates, use the following command to interrupt the process:

```
sudo pkill apt
sudo pkill dpkg
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```